# How to add Excel Web Access Web part into my sharepoint gallery?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, web, sharepoint-2010

please, can you help me on how to add **Excel Web Access** Web part into my sharepoint gallery?

I need to see an Excel sheet in sharepoint and I just can't find this feature.

Is this web part supposed to be manually downloaded?

Is my sharepoint version that might be not allowing me to have it?

I can't even see the category "business data" where Excel is supposed to be at the examples that I saw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel Web Access is only available in SharePoint Server (rather than the free SharePoint Foundation).